# Problem matching regex pattern in Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to search this string:

```
,"tt" : "ABC","r" : "+725.00","a" : "55.30",
```

For:

```
"r" : "725.00"
```

And here is my current code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([r]\".:.\"[+|-][0-9]+.[0-9][0-9]\")");
Matcher m = p.matcher(raw_string);
```

I've been trying multiple variations of the pattern, and a match is never found.  A second set of eyes would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regexp actually works, it's almost correct

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[r]\".:.\"[+|-][0-9]+.[0-9][0-9]\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(raw_string);
if (m.find()){
    String res = m.toMatchResult().group(0);
}
```

Comment: Matcher ISA MatchResult, so `m.group(0)` (or even `m.group()`) will suffice.  +1 for catching the missing quote, and for getting rid of the all-encompassing capturing group.

Answer (score 4):

The next line should read:

```
if ( m.find() ) {
```

Are you doing that?

A few other issues: You're using `.` to match the spaces surrounding the colon; if that's always supposed to be whitespace, you should use `+` (one or more spaces) or `\s+` (one or more whitespace characters).  On the other hand, the dot between the digits is supposed to match a literal `.`, so you should escape it: `\.` Of course, since this is a Java String literal, you need to escape the backslashes: `\\s+`, `\\.`.

You don't need the square brackets around the `r`, and if you don't want to match a `|` in front of the number you should change `[+|-]` to `[+-]`.

While some of these issues I've mentioned could result in false positives, none of them would *prevent* it from matching valid input.  That's why I suspect you aren't actually applying the regex by calling `find()`.  It's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First thing try to escape your dot symbol: ...`[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]`...
because the dot symbol match any character...

Second thing: the `[+|-]`define a range of characters but it's mandatory...
try `[+|-]?`

Alban.

Comment: The literal dot is inside the range of "any char", so the match will happen, BTW your suggest of [+|-]? will also match "r" : "|725.00", because characters inside brackets(sequence) doesnt need the "OR" operator